# Can header redirects in PHP be used when checking sensitive data

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently started learning a bit of PHP for a small website project, using MySQL also. I believe it's a pretty common combination for small sites. I am working on a simple authorisation script, literally comparing user-submitted password to a hard-coded value (I'll improve this as it gets more complicated).

My question is, on a secured page, where the user needs to be logged in to access it, is it a good idea to check if a session exists (I'm using sessions), and if it doesn't (the user's not logged in), just apply a header() redirect to the login page or is this unsecure? Can the header() redirect be skipped in any way? If it is unsecure, which is the best way to do it?

Comment: It's fine to have a boolean session variable to say the user is logged in, as long as the only way for the app to set it is to receive a valid password. However as time goes on you may wish to look up the current user in order to examine their permissions or profile, in which case you may wish to put the user's username/ID in the session instead.

Comment: Yes, once I populate the user/pass table in the db, I'll read about password security and encryption :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to add `exit()` after the header - otherwise you won't actually stop execution. `header()` only adds the header, while execution continues afterward.

```
if ($pass != "foobar") {
    header("Location: /");
}

// allow logged in user stuff here
```

.. will result in a redirect for a non-logged in user, but only after the script has finished running (and everything beneath "allow logged in .." will execute as if the user was logged in).

```
if ($pass != "foobar") {
    header("Location: /");
    exit();
}
```

.. will terminate execution after the header call, and no further code will be run.

Comment: Thanks! I have now added exit() :)